# Perl Error: thread failed to start: Invalid value for shared scalar

Tags: multithreading, perl

I get the following error when trying to run my test code:

`thread failed to start: Invalid value for shared scalar at ./threaded_test.pl line 47.`

Line 47 is:
`%hoh = hoh(@new_array);`

My observations:

- If I remove line 47 and other lines referencing `%hoh`, then the script runs without errors
- I can create a new hash `%new_hash = (itchy => "Scratchy");` without errors, but when I try to "return" a hash from another sub (line 47), it results in the error above.

Unfortunately, I cannot use a in/out Queue because the version of Thread::Queue that I use is too old (and installed on a system I have no control over) and doesn't support hash and hash-ref types to be returned via a Queue (according to [this](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=763712)). Apparently, my version only support strings to be returned via queues.

Is there a way to successfully do this: `$hash{$string}{"jc"} = \%hoh;`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use threads;
use Thread::Queue;
use constant NUM_WORKERS => 10;

my @out_array : shared = ();
main();

sub main
{
    my @results = test1();
    foreach my $item (@results) {
        print "item: $item\n";
    }
}

sub test1
{
    my $my_queue = Thread::Queue->new();
    foreach (1..NUM_WORKERS) {
        async {
            while (my $job = $my_queue->dequeue()) {
                test2($job);
            }
        };
    }
    my @sentiments = ("Axe Murderer", "Mauler", "Babyface", "Dragon");
    $my_queue->enqueue(@sentiments);
    $my_queue->enqueue(undef) for 1..NUM_WORKERS;
    $_->join() for threads->list();
    my @return_array = @out_array;
    return @return_array;   
}

sub test2
{
    my $string = $_[0];
    my %hash : shared;
    my @new_array : shared;
    my %new_hash : shared;
    my %hoh : shared;
    @new_array = ("tom", "jerry");
    %new_hash = (itchy => "Scratchy");
    %hoh = hoh(@new_array);
    my %anon : shared;

    $hash{$string} = \%anon;    
    $hash{$string}{"Grenade"} = \@new_array;
    $hash{$string}{"Pipe bomb"} = \%new_hash;
    $hash{$string}{"jc"} = \%hoh;
    push @out_array, \%hash;
    return;
}

sub hoh
{
    my %hoh;
    foreach my $item (@_) {
        $hoh{"jeepers"}{"creepers"} = $item;
    }
    return %hoh;
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can return a hash from a sub, only a reference to it (\%hoh).  Then dereference using -> .  See http://perlmeme.org/faqs/perl_thinking/returning.html

Comment: also, `$hoh{"jeepers"}{"creepers"}` will always be the last element in the arg list calling the `hoh()` subroutine

Comment: If you can install a script, you can install a module. You don't need any special permissions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your trying to store a reference to something that isn't shared in a shared variable. You need to use `share` as previously mentioned, or you need to serialise the data structure.

Comment: Thanks. Your explantion here is worded a bit differently and adds to my store of understanding :) I change it to `return share(%hoh);` and it now works.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/perl/bin/perl

use strict;
use threads;
use threads::shared;

my %hm_n2g:shared = ();

my $row = &share([]);
$hm_n2g{"aa"}=$row;
$row->[0]=1;
$row->[1]=2;
my @arr = @{$hm_n2g{"aa"}};
print @arr[0]." ".@arr[1]."\n";

#If you want to lock the hash in a thread-subroutine
{
lock(%hm_n2g)

}
```